# With spring and hibernate, need clarification on how the datasource and session are wired

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, spring-mvc

My DAO's are going to extend the `HibernateDaoSupport` class that spring provides.

Now I need to:

1. setup my database connection in web.xml
2. Tell spring I am using annotations for hibernate mapping?
3. wire the session to the HibernateDaoSupport object.

The doc's show a sample xml:

```
<beans>

  <bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost:9001"/>
    <property name="username" value="sa"/>
    <property name="password" value=""/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="mySessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource"/>
    <property name="mappingResources">
      <list>
        <value>product.hbm.xml</value>
      </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
      <value>
        hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
      </value>
    </property>
  </bean>

</beans>
```

So the 'mydatasource' configures the connection to the database, and the mySessionFactory sets up the session.

What I am confused with is, where in the code are these beans being used?

I want to create a `GenericDaoImpl` that extends`HibernateDaoSupport`.  I will then create `EntityDaoImpl` that extend GenericDaoImpl.

**Just confused as to where 'mydatasource' and 'mysessionFactory' are used internally.  Shouldn't they both be properties to `HibernateDaoSupport`?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Shouldn't they both be properties to
>   HibernateDaoSupport?

Well, `SessionFactory` should. The DAO won't need the `DataSource`, since that's used internally by the `SessionFactory`. Your own code should have no need for the raw `DataSource`, and so should not have to be injected with it.

Your DAOs (which extend `HibernateDaoSupport`) need to injected with the `SessionFactory` bean, e.g.

```
public class DaoA extends HibernateDaoSupport {
   // business methods here, that use getHibernateTemplate()
}

public class DaoB extends HibernateDaoSupport {
   // business methods here, that use getHibernateTemplate()
}
```

---

```
<bean id="daoA" class="DaoA">
   <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="daoB" class="DaoB">
   <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Ah ok, but since I am using a GenericDao that each EntityDao will inherit from, I just need to do this once! cool.

Comment: So your saying the 'mydatasource' is simply for the 'mysessionfactory' bean to reference, in code there really shouldn't be any references to the 'mydatasource' bean?  Its only referenced in the .xml for the sessionFactory correct?

Comment: Spring is going to require you to declare a <bean> for each GenericDao implementation you want to use - otherwise Spring won't know to create the instance